# How to cast a reference to pointer to pointer to pointer

Tags: pointers, reference, casting, double, memory-address

I have a pointer void* p which points to X object. How can I make a void** p2 pointer which points to p pointer? The reason I want to do this is that position of X object may change after remapping it so I want *p2 to always access the new address. I wanted to achieve this by casting &p to void**, but this did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from your question as to whether you have tried this:

```
int x = 10;
void* p = &x;
void** p2 = &p;
```

This creates a pointer `p2` which points at `p1`, which in turn points to `x`.

Comment: uhm, actually I tried to store &x in a void* p2 and passed it through parameters (because I want to have a function), but when I dereferenced it, it did not point to X. Was it because I should have did it void** and pass void** as a whole through parameters?

Comment: I have explained my problem in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143388/reference-stored-in-pointer-gives-different-results-how-so, well but maybe its incomprehensible, since ivve got no replies :) ?

Comment: I made an unrelated bug because of which this did not work, but so the answer is correct, so I marked it as answered.